# Angular nvd3 : Zooming on a line chart

Tags: javascript, angularjs, nvd3.js

I am currently implementing a directive that plots a `lineChart` using [Angular nvD3](http://krispo.github.io/angular-nvd3/#/). I am trying to implement a a zoom directly on the graph instead of using the slider that could be found with the `lineWithFocusChart`.
Instead I plan to click and drag on the graph to zoom just like [fusion charts](http://www.fusioncharts.com/charts/zoom-scroll-charts/) does. Is there a way to do so?

Also, is there a way to retrieve the position of the mouse upon a click on the graph?

Thank you in advance :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If anyone is still looking, try adding this to your chart options:

```
zoom: {
    enabled: true,
    scaleExtent: [1, 10],
    useFixedDomain: false,
    useNiceScale: false,
    horizontalOff: false,
    verticalOff: true,
    unzoomEventType: "dblclick.zoom"
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Is there a way to control `zoomEventType` itself? or is it always set to "mouse scroll"? Can I set to a different event like "Shift + Mouse Scroll"?

Comment: @sinapan this was a million years ago in my world :) but yes, I believe you can set some type of listener for "shift + mouse scroll" that would do the zooming work.

Comment: Thank you. but I can't find the option's name in the documentation here - http://krispo.github.io/angular-nvd3/#/quickstart do you what the option is called to control zooming in? there is `unzoomEventType` (which is for zooming out) but no `zoomEventType` in the documentation. That's my main issue. Any suggestions?

Comment: You will probably have to listen for the keyboard event and change the chart scale when the press those buttons.